# Meterial 2 md-datepicker-toggle is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

After import `MdDatepickerModule` and `MdNativeDateModule`, in my html:

```
<input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="startPicker" placeholder="Choose a date">
<md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="startPicker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
<md-datepicker #startPicker></md-datepicker>
```

And it has error that: oc-datepicker-toggle is not a known element.

Comment: which version of material 2 ?

Comment: I'm using Material 2.0.0-beta.8

Comment: please see my answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<md-datepicker-toggle>` was introduced in Material **2.0.0-beta.10**. See this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-d%C3%A9coupage-panjandrum-2017-08-29) for more details.

> **mdDatepickerToggle** is now an element **< md-datepicker-toggle >** with a for
>   property that points to the MdDatepicker instance.

If you are using an earlier version of Material 2, then using `<md-datepicker-toggle>` will throw this error. To update to the new version, do the following:

- In your `package.json`, change `"@angular/material"` and `"@angular/cdk"` version to `"2.0.0-beta.10"`
- In your terminal window, navigate to the folder in your project where `package.json` is located.
- Run the command `npm install`

Here is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-76wdyx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) using version 2.0.0-beta.10.